# Wrong icons when I run the aplication in release mode in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I just finished an application with flutter and while I run it in debug mode everything is fine, but when I switch to --profile or --release mode it changes all the icons that I use and puts others, even the navigation arrows of the application.

Comment: update your flutter version

Comment: What you mean by  the icons ?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this error before while locally testing on a device with an .apk file directly generated from `flutter build`.

It fixed itself once I tested from the play store.

I found that when directly testing flutter build .apk files, there are issues as there are different processor types [armeabi-v7a](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis#v7a) (ARM 32-bit), [arm64-v8a](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis#arm64-v8a) (ARM 64-bit), and [x86-64](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis#86-64) (x86 64-bit).

If you are testing locally I would recommend:

1. Building an `app bundle` using `flutter build appbundle` in
   terminal.
2. Using the `bundletool` from the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/google/bundletool/releases/latest).
3. [Generate a set of APKs](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool#generate_apks) from your app bundle.
4. [Deploy the APKs](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool#deploy_with_bundletool) to connected devices.

[Source](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#test-the-app-bundle)